# confusing Subject-Verb Agreement in one quote

Tags: subjunctive-mood, verb-agreement

what though life **conspire** to cheat you

---

I think this quote has a wrong part. 
I know Singular subjects need singular verbs; so should the verb "conspire" agree to the subject "life" like "conspires"?

Comment: Your quote doesn't make any sense in English, and we can only guess at its meaning, which makes it difficult to give a proper answer.  Can you give the complete sentence?

Comment: @deadrat: I've edited "live" to read "life" (as in the original poem; well, translated, perhaps).

Answer (score 1):

(I've edited the question's original "live" to read "life")

> What though life conspire to cheat you

is from a poem with the same title by [Pushkin](http://iambrucewang.blogspot.fr/2009/01/what-though-life-conspire-to-cheat-you.html).

"Conspire" here is an example of the third person subjunctive, implying a hypothetical state:

> It’s used to explore hypotheticals:
>
> If I were to embroider a sampler, it would say, “Simple is truly best in Frytown.” [Z Wire] - *[Grammarist](http://grammarist.com/grammar/subjunctive-mood/)*

The meaning of the start of the line is something like: "Imagine that life were to conspire..."

Comment: Are you sure it's  _third person subjunctive_, and not a conditional _bare infinitive_?